# "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error goes away after building project

Tags: android, r.java-file

I am getting the "R cannot be resolved to a variable" error all of a sudden. I read another thread on this issue and it says to update the android build tools to make the error go away but that did not fix it.  But for some reason the error goes away when I build the project.

What is going on here?

Comment: Does error come every time you create the new project?

Comment: That is a possible error of your .xml layouts. Try to fix them and before that try 'Clean project'

Comment: There will be an import line like `import android.R;`. Just remove this line, clean your project and done.

Comment: Either do what user3264399 wrote, or just delete `R.java` (under `gen` folder) from the build and let eclipse re-generate it.

Answer (score 5):

I found this happening to me with a broken layout. No need to be worry. I am trying my best to giving you the solution:

**Solution:**

- Make sure that anything the **R.** links to is not broken. Fix all
  errors in your XML files. If anything in the ADKs are broken, R will
  not regenerate.
- If you somehow hit something and created import `android.R` in your
  activity, remove it.
- Run **Project -> Clean.** This will delete and regenerate R and
  BuildConfig.
- Make sure **Project -> Build** Automatically is ticked. If not, build
  it manually via **Menu -> Project -> Build Project .**

Wait a few seconds for the errors to disappear.

If it doesn't work:

- delete everything inside the **/gen/** folder

If it still doesn't work:

- try right-clicking your **project -> Android Tools -> Fix** Project
  Properties.

Check your *.properties files (in the root folder of your app folder) and make sure that the links in there are not broken.

Right-click your **project > properties >** Android.

Look at the Project Build Target and Library sections on the right side of the page. Your Build Target should match the target in your AndroidManifest.xml. So if it's set to target 17 in AndroidManifest, make sure that the Target Name is Android 4.2. If your Library has an X under the reference, remove and re-add the library until there's a green tick. This might happen if you've moved a few files and folders around.

**What to do if R doesn't regenerate**

- This usually happens when you have a broken xml file.
- Check errors inside your XML files, mainly within the **/res/**
  folder
- Common places are **/layout/** and **/values/** especially if you've
  changed one of them recently
- Check **AndroidManifest.xml**, I find that often I change a string,
  and forget to change the string name from AndroidManifest.xml.
- Check that Android SDK Build-tools is installed. **Window->Android
  SDK Manager->Tools->Android SDK Build-tools**
- Make sure when you update the Android SDK Tools, you also update the
  Android SDK Platform-tools and Android ASK Build-tools. Build fails
  silently if they don't match.

If you can't find the issue:

- right click **/gen/ -> Restore from local history... -> tick R.java
  -> click Restore.** This doesn't solve the problem, but it will clear out the extra errors to make the problem easier to find.

Hope it will help you. :)

Comment: Yap I have given all the way to solve the error. @user3124880

Comment: I think now anyone can solve all the error related to R by this ans. @user3073115

Comment: Thanks for the details (voted^). I followed your instructions step by step until the end. After one of the builds it couldn't detect the `Object` class. It only worked when I 1) **closed** Eclipse 2) **Project->Clean** (deleting gen) 3) Right-clicked proj and **Android Tools->Fix** 4) **Project->Build Project**.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the `Build Automically` in eclipse's `Project` menu?

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

- Open your activity file
- Search for this line `import android.R;`
- Delete that line
- Clean the project
- Done.

Answer (score 0):

This Will Happen when Your Eclipse has more Than 10 projects...

I faced this problem in **New Work space** also which have only one project..

So only one solution when you **Running/Debugging** an android Application..

Before that You need to do

1.Save all Files.

2.**Clean**  **clean**  **clean** the projects in work space..

3.after Cleaning wait for 5sec. then Run your app..

there are some references

[1. how-to-solve-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable](http://artproblogger.com/how-to-solve-r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable-in-android-eclipse-mainactivity-java/)

[2.r-cannot-be-resolved-to-variable](http://androidanddevelopment.blogspot.in/2013/07/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-variable.html)

But If you get this error I suggest
2 things

1.`Cut and paste` src(.java) and resource(xml layout) files and then Save all together

or

2.You need to `Build Your Project in New Work Space`..

or

3.and check this  `import android.R;` for every java file..

Follow This Procedure..So that Error Will be no more..

Comment: Hi Madhu.. This is the Process worked For me when i am Using and existing IDE or Android Build tools IDE.. Thanks a lot Great.. work..

Comment: Yes this will the Exact Reason of Getting That error,.. And this will work fine.. Great.

Comment: k man Now satisfied.. But what about me and Remove that bad comment... On me.. Dont be Jealous man... If some one Downvote Your Question that's their mistake.. why you repeat same mistake on me.. Its not fair.. Please encourage us.. i am an up-vote person.. i know what is cost of down-vote,, Please stop Blaming me..

Answer (score 0):

Are you importing the android.R or the one in your own project?
you are doing mistake in your xml files.,check your xm lfiles.

Are you sure your own R.java file is generated? Mistakes in your xml views could cause the R.java not to be generated. Go through your view files and make sure all the xml is right!